# SecurityException: The number of child package elements exceeded the max allowed in queries

Tags: package, android-manifest, limit, android-securityexception, android-14

On android 14 I get an error when adding more than 1000  elements inside a  element in AndroidManifest.
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The number of child package elements exceeded the max allowed in queries.

There is no such error on versions before Android 14.

What is the limit of  elements inside a  element?

need to add 8000  elements.